# Android Back button work in a wrong way

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have an issue: I have 3 activities (1 -> 2 -> 3). Each of them start another activity like:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainMenuActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

But when I am pressing BACK BUTTON on 3 activity - it stops application instead of moving me to 2 activity. I did not override onKeyDown method. What can it be? How to solve this?

Thanks.

Does it say somesing to you? This is the flow of switching between activities: 1 - 2- 3 - 2 (black screen).

```
10-24 23:56:02.231: I/ActivityManager(237): Displayed com.example.runner/.StartActivity: +26s885ms
10-24 23:56:02.241: V/WindowManager(237): Starting animation in AppWindowToken{41b973c0 token=Token{40fdcf98 ActivityRecord{4128fb00 com.example.runner/.StartActivity}}} @ 79703124
10-24 23:56:02.241: V/WindowManager(237): Finished animation in AppWindowToken{41b973c0 token=Token{40fdcf98 ActivityRecord{4128fb00 com.example.runner/.StartActivity}}} @ 79703124
10-24 23:56:02.241: V/WindowManager(237): Starting animation in AppWindowToken{41a78ef8 token=Token{413e4ab0 ActivityRecord{412d8708 com.example.runner/.SportEventResultActivity}}} @ 79703124
10-24 23:56:02.321: D/memalloc(19422): /dev/pmem: Unmapping buffer base:0x522a7000 size:8355840 offset:6266880
10-24 23:56:02.321: D/memalloc(112): /dev/pmem: Freeing buffer base:0x4260a000 size:2088960 offset:6266880 fd:41
10-24 23:56:02.321: D/memalloc(19422): /dev/pmem: Unmapping buffer base:0x51ede000 size:2088960 offset:0
10-24 23:56:02.321: D/ActivityManager(237): destroyActivityLocked, r=ActivityRecord{412d8708 com.example.runner/.SportEventResultActivity}
10-24 23:56:02.321: V/ActivityManager(237): destroyActivityLocked, dalvik.system.VMStack.getThreadStackTrace(Native Method)
10-24 23:56:02.321: V/ActivityManager(237): destroyActivityLocked, java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:599)
10-24 23:56:02.321: V/ActivityManager(237): destroyActivityLocked, com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.destroyActivityLocked(ActivityStack.java:3754)
10-24 23:56:02.321: V/ActivityManager(237): destroyActivityLocked, com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.finishCurrentActivityLocked(ActivityStack.java:3621)
10-24 23:56:02.321: V/ActivityManager(237): destroyActivityLocked, com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.finishCurrentActivityLocked(ActivityStack.java:3578)
10-24 23:56:02.321: V/ActivityManager(237): destroyActivityLocked, com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.activityIdleInternal(ActivityStack.java:3410)
10-24 23:56:02.321: V/ActivityManager(237): destroyActivityLocked, com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.activityIdle(ActivityManagerService.java:4313)
10-24 23:56:02.321: V/ActivityManager(237): destroyActivityLocked, android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:362)
10-24 23:56:02.321: V/ActivityManager(237): destroyActivityLocked, com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:1699)
10-24 23:56:02.321: V/ActivityManager(237): destroyActivityLocked, android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:338)
10-24 23:56:02.321: V/ActivityManager(237): destroyActivityLocked, dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
10-24 23:56:02.331: D/ActivityManager(237): destroyActivityLocked, r=ActivityRecord{412b3430 com.example.runner/.MainMenuActivity}
10-24 23:56:02.331: V/ActivityManager(237): destroyActivityLocked, dalvik.system.VMStack.getThreadStackTrace(Native Method)
10-24 23:56:02.331: V/ActivityManager(237): destroyActivityLocked, java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:599)
10-24 23:56:02.331: V/ActivityManager(237): destroyActivityLocked, com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.destroyActivityLocked(ActivityStack.java:3754)
10-24 23:56:02.331: V/ActivityManager(237): destroyActivityLocked, com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.activityIdleInternal(ActivityStack.java:3422)
10-24 23:56:02.331: V/ActivityManager(237): destroyActivityLocked, com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.activityIdle(ActivityManagerService.java:4313)
10-24 23:56:02.331: V/ActivityManager(237): destroyActivityLocked, android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:362)
10-24 23:56:02.331: V/ActivityManager(237): destroyActivityLocked, com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:1699)
10-24 23:56:02.331: V/ActivityManager(237): destroyActivityLocked, android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:338)
10-24 23:56:02.331: V/ActivityManager(237): destroyActivityLocked, dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
10-24 23:56:02.462: D/memalloc(112): /dev/pmem: Freeing buffer base:0x42010000 size:2088960 offset:0 fd:29
10-24 23:56:02.462: V/WindowManager(237): Finished animation in AppWindowToken{41a78ef8 token=Token{413e4ab0 ActivityRecord{412d8708 com.example.runner/.SportEventResultActivity}}} @ 79703354
```

Comment: Make sure that you are not calling `finish()` after the intent for starting another activity.

Comment: Is it going to home screen or crashing? If its crashing then please post the logcat

Comment: It is going to home screen. No errors.

Comment: Then yes, make sure you aren't calling `finish()` in the previous `Activities`, have `noHistory` declared in your `manifest`, or have "don't keep Activities" checked in your device

Comment: Can we have a look at your code for Activity 3?

Comment: are you setting android:noHistory="true" to those activities in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: 2 Sam_D: Thanks! I had this parameter switched. When I put there false all is working great now. Thanks!!